# UIBezierpaths Are Not Drawing Where They Were Drawn

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibezierpath, swift4.2

Looking for help on this "weird" problem.

I am using a PanGesture to allow the user to draw a line on `CAShapeLayer`.

I keep track of the path until they end and then store the path in an array of paths, clearing their original path from the `CAShapeLayer.path`

When I redraw those paths onto a `UIImage`, the paths are shifted in the `Y-axis` towards the top of the screen.

I am attaching two images:

1) The drawing of the path. [Drawing The Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaAjQ.png)

2) The UIImage that is put out when I redraw the path. As you can see, I draw along a grid line, however, when the UIImage is created, the line is above the grid line. [The Path Redrawn On UIImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3XSL.png)

Any suggestions appreciated.

The **code** for both the drawing and then the rendering are below.

```
    @objc private func drawLine(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
    if point.x < 0 || point.x > self.bounds.width || point.y < 0 || point.y > self.bounds.height {
      return
    }

    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case .began:
      currentLine = UIBezierPath()
      currentLine.lineWidth = settings.defaultSpotRadius
      currentLine.lineCapStyle = .round
      currentLine.lineJoinStyle = .round
      currentLine.move(to: point)
      break

    case .changed:
      currentLine.addLine(to: point)
      currentLineDrawLayer.path = currentLine.cgPath
      break

    case .ended:
      self.storage.addLine(clear: fowClearMode, path: currentLine, ofWidth: currentLine.lineWidth)
      currentLineDrawLayer.path = nil
      storedImage = drawPaths()
      break

    default:
      break
    }

  }

  public func drawPaths() -> UIImage? {
    if pathsHidden { return nil }

    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.imageSize)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)

    storedImage.draw(in: rect)

    for (isClear, line, width) in thePaths {
      let blendMode = isClear ? settings.colorClear : settings.colorDark
      line.lineWidth = width
      line.stroke(with: blendMode, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
  }
```

### Tue 25 Sep, 2018

I have created a mini-project that contains only the import bits and pieces. It is available here ... [Mini-Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kezo7uo0jfj0qxg/uibezier01.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Is the `self.imageSize` property you use to create the image context exactly same size as the bounds of the view in which you detect `gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)`?

Comment: imageSize is the exact size of the original image yes. It is the same at all times. I have not done any scaling or sizing.

Comment: @fly.ing.fox -- based on the images you posted, the re-drawn line is shifted both "up" and "to the right". It's possible you need to translate the coordinates into the proper coordinate space. If you post a minimal "runnable" code example, it would be easier to help. See [mcve]

Comment: @DonMag -- when you mention translating the coordinates - since I am using let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self) would this not ensure that when I redraw that point it should be in the correct space?

Comment: @fly.ing.fox - in theory, yes... but hard to tell from what you've posted. Your two images are not identical in size, and the "grid lines" don't quite match up. Is it possible your imageView is not the same size as your image, and is therefore doing the scaling without you realizing it?

Comment: @DonMag - The two images I put up were cropped from screenshots (maybe not perfectly) ... the gridlines all line up technically. I did not want to upload larger files. The images were really just to show to fact that the path draws higher. If you draw along a grid line, it redraws in the UIImage above the line as shown. Since it is late here in my neck of the woods I will look at creating a mini-project that illustrates my issue tomorrow.

Comment: @DonMag -- I have put a mini-project up on Dropbox and supplied the link. It is the bare bones of what I am doing with hardcoded values instead of values loaded in from JSON.

Comment: @fly.ing.fox - you've got something wrong going on with your image sizing. When I run your sample app in Portrait orientation on an iPad, it is ***way*** off. In Landscape orientation, I get the same result as the screen-caps you posted. If I change your `aPathImage = PathImage(...)` line from `CGSize(width: 1024, height: 791)` to `CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768)` (to match iPad Landscape orientation) everything lines up perfectly.

Comment: @DonMag -- it is not supposed to run in portrait (at this stage). I am sure I clicked only landscape for the app. And yes, if I force the image to match the screen size then all is well, however, the user may load up images that are larger than the screen (or smaller and it will get resized). The gridline image is 1024 by 791, thus the CGSize. The difference is 23 points which does not look like the difference on screen, however I will check that with the demo project.

Comment: @DonMag -- I have modified the project to force landscape only. There was an extra portrait mode in the info.plist. I also added a blue and red line as thick as the pen to test if it was shifting by the image size of 791 vs 768 (23). It is not ... so here I am thinking that it is a frame vs. bounds problem HOWEVER I have gone through and ensured (I think) that all the frames match. Any suggestions?

Comment: @fly.ing.fox - hmmm... you've got a couple quirky things going on. Is your goal to scale the image to fit the screen, while maintaining its aspect ratio? Or, do you want the image to remain at its "native" size, centered on the screen?

Comment: @DonMag — long term goal is to allow scaling by aspect ratio as well as panning. Short term goal is sorting out this shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a ways to go to get everything working as desired, but, to solve your initial "offset" issue...

In `ViewController.swift` you are setting the frame of `imgDisplay: ImageDisplay` to `self.view.bounds` --- which, in this case, will be `1024 x 768`.

Then in `ImageDisplay.swift` you create `aPathImage` at a size of `1024 x 791` and setting that image as a sublayer.

Then...

You are tracking pan-gestures based on a view with bounds of `1024 x 768`, then re-drawing those lines on an image that is `1024 x 791`, resulting in a "shift".

Note that, if you change your image size to `800 x 600` the shift will be very obvious, and it will be a little easier to see how it is related to the size difference.

What you probably want to do is set the size of the frame of `imgDisplay` to the size of the image.

Try this to see what happens - in `ImageDisplay.swift`:

```
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    // add this line        
    self.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: aPathImage.sizeCurrent)

    self.contentMode = .center
    ...
```

Now, your pan coordinates will match the coordinates of the contained image.

As I said, you've still got a ways to go, but hopefully this helps you along the way.

Comment: seems like you figured out the problem, I was missing a frame size somewhere but looking at the code for too long made me skip it. For now it seems like it works thus I will be awarding the answer to you :)